# Проблема с массивом и обработкой данных

Tags: c#, массивы

Задача: нужно через консоль задать количество работников и далее указать их зарплату. Проблемы начинаются с указания массива, и либо его неправильная инициализация, либо я уже не знаю что, про массивы читал - пробовал - не получилось, теперь конкретно к коду:

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AverageSalary
{
    class Sravnenie 
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] SalaryList;
            Console.WriteLine("Введите колличество сотрудников: ");
            int  NumberOfWorkers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            SalaryList = new int[NumberOfWorkers];      
            for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfWorkers; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Введлите зарплату сотрудника {0.d} : ", i);
                int SalaryOfEachWorker = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                SalaryList[i] = SalaryOfEachWorker;

            }  

            Console.WriteLine(SalaryList);    

        } 
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что консоль выдает `System.Int32[]`.

Comment: @AlexF пробовал,даже только что - проблема одна и та же: System.Int32[] на выводе

Comment: В `Console.WriteLine(SalaryList);` неявно вызывается метод `ToString()` у массива, который в общем случае просто выводит имя класса. Вам нужно написать дополнительный код по выводу массива в нужном виде. Инициализировать массив нужно, как вам уже написали, через `SalaryList = new int[NumberOfWorkers];`. С условием остановки цикла у вас тоже что-то непонятное. Откуда 4? Делайте от `i = 0` до `i < NumberOfWorkers`.

Comment: `4 <= i` - это тоже самое, что `i >= 4`, это условие ни разу не срабатывает, внутрь цикла вы не попадаете.

Comment: @CrazyElf 4 места не имеет, вставлялась исключительно для поиска проблемы....

Comment: @LeeroyskiyGames Если у вас код в вопросе отличается от реального кода, то как мы вообще можем вам помочь??

Comment: @CrazyElf внес правки до момента ошибки, дабы не запутать

Comment: @MaxS Console.WriteLine(SalaryList.ToString());  верно? Если да, то также не помогло

Comment: Нет, ToString() у вас и так вызывается, но он вам не помощник в данном случае. Добавил ответ на ваш вопрос, почитайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `Console.WriteLine(SalaryList)` неявно вызывается метод [`ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-5.0) у массива, который по умолчанию просто выводит полное имя класса – в вашем случае это `System.Int32[]`.

Если вы хотите вывести массив поэлементно, нужно написать немного дополнительного кода. Проще всего воспользоваться встроенным методом [`String.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=windowsdesktop-3.0): `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', SalaryList))`.

Весь ваш код метода Main тогда будет выглядеть так (привел заодно имена всех переменных в соответствии с [соглашениями о написании кода на C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions) и исправил пару недочетов):

```
int[] salaries;
Console.WriteLine("Введите количество сотрудников: ");
int workersCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
salaries = new int[workersCount];
for (int i = 0; i < workersCount; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Введите зарплату сотрудника {i + 1}: ");
    int salaryOfWorker = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    salaries[i] = salaryOfWorker;
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', salaries));
```